# What characteristics qualify a character of being "Worthy" of Mjolnir?

Tags: mjolnir

Mjolnir is one of the constantly talked about icons of the Marvel universe. The main question is generally *who* is/has been capable of wielding it, and, as it turns out, quite a few over the years. (Good on ya guys).

But my question is more about the qualities that allow a person to be granted worthiness by Mjolnir, or, to put it another way, what qualities in a person does Mjolnir deem as "being worthy"?

The most surprising characters (I believe) are:

- [(Natalia) Romanov aka. Black Widow. (Earth 23223)](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Natalia_Romanova_(Earth-23223))

  > While the others used themselves as a distraction for the serpent it allowed Widow to go on a retrieval mission to find Thor's hammer, Mjolnir. While she saw the Quinjet purposely torpedo itself in a kamikaze attack on Jormungand, Natasha was found worthy to pick up Mjolnir which allowed her to become the new Goddess of Thunder.

  As an assassin and a spy for most of her life, her track record doesn't exactly show qualities that most would really consider as "good".
- [Hulk](http://au.ign.com/articles/2014/09/30/12-other-characters-who-have-lifted-thors-hammer-mjolnir)

  > Hulk being the strongest one there is, he's attempted to lift Mjolnir with varying degrees of success in their many battles. Perhaps the closest Hulk has come to truly lifting Mjolnir was in Avengers Assemble #4. Thor attempted to wallop Thanos with Mjolnir, only for Thanos to mind-control Hulk and force the Jade Giant to catch the hammer. Hulk was able to both deflect Mjolnir and whack Thor in the face with it. Granted, Thor was still holding onto Mjolnir throughout the brief skirmish, but we'll give Hulk the accomplishment all the same.

Ok, so maybe not the last one so much, as other characters have been able to lift it unassisted (such as Vision and "The Destroyer", who have also been able to lift it unassisted, without being bestowed the powers of Thor).

So, my question is, **what are the qualities that make a person worthy of wielding Mjolnir?**

Comment: @Richard Of course you *would* be the one to catch this! ;-) But where the hell is Thaddeus when you need him, and why hasn't he answered the older question?

Comment: +1 for a good question. It just so happens that the question has already been asked before. Duplicate questions are not a bad thing, though, so don't worry about anything. :)